# Создание WebSocket подключения в Service

Tags: java, android, websocket, android-service

Столкнулся с проблемой,  создания подключения по `WebSocket` в `Service`. Использую библиотеку `org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient`.

При попытке вызнать в сервисе метод  `startTestWebSocket`  что  бы создать подключение ( и оно создается ), а потом вызнавать метод
`sendMessage` ловлю `NullPointer`. Думал что это из-за того что  каждый  экшен выполняется в отдельном потоке, т.е. конекшн  создается в одном,
а вызов метода для отправки сообщения уже в другом. После этого я попробовал делать это в одном потоке, но все равно ловлю ошибку.

Далее я попробовал выполнить эти два метода просто в активити - и в активити  все работает.
Вопрос:  как можно организовать работу веб-сокета в фоновом режиме, и почему мой  вариант не работает?

Код сервиса,  и активити в котором код работает нормально привожу ниже.

**WebSocketService.java**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class WebSocketService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "WebSocketService";
    private static final String ACTION_TEST_WEB_SOCKET_CLIENT = "ACTION_TEST_WEB_SOCKET_CLIENT";
    private static final String ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE = "ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE";

    private static final String HOST = "192.168.1.103";
    private static final String PORT = "8080";

    final String wsuri = "ws://" + HOST + ":" + PORT;

    WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
    ServerHandshake myServerHandshake;

    private WebSocketConnection  mConnection = new WebSocketConnection ();


    public WebSocketService() {
        super("WebSocketService");
    }


    public static void startTestWebSocket(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "startTestWebSocket");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebSocketService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_TEST_WEB_SOCKET_CLIENT);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void startSendMessage(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "startSendMessage");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebSocketService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");

        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_TEST_WEB_SOCKET_CLIENT:
                Log.d(TAG, "MyService.ACTION_TEST_WEB_SOCKET_CLIENT");
                testWebSocketClient();
                break;
            case ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE:
                Log.d(TAG, "MyService.ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE");
                sendMessage();
                break;
        }

    }


    private void sendMessage() {
        mWebSocketClient.send("Test text");
    }


    private void testWebSocketClient() {

        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(wsuri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {

            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {

                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                Log.d(TAG, s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        mWebSocketClient.connect();

        sendMessage();
    }
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    private static final String HOST = "192.168.1.103";
    private static final String PORT = "8080";

    final String wsuri = "ws://" + HOST + ":" + PORT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

        connectWebSocket();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private void connectWebSocket() {

        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(wsuri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);
                        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        mWebSocketClient.send(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText("");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему использованием `Service` вместо `IntentService`. Судя по всему проблема была таки в том, что в `connection` и последующее обращение к нему происходили в разных  потоках. Ниже привожу код рабочего сервиса:

**WebSocketService.java**

```
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class WebSocketService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "WebSocketService";

    private static final String ACTION_CONNECT_WEB_SOCKET = "ACTION_CONNECT_WEB_SOCKET";
    private static final String ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE = "ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE";

    private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    private static final String HOST = "192.168.1.103";
    private static final String PORT = "8080";

    final String wsuri = "ws://" + HOST + ":" + PORT;

    public static void startWebSocket(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "startWebSocket");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebSocketService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_CONNECT_WEB_SOCKET);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public static void startSendMessage(Context context) {
        Log.e(TAG, "startSendMessage");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebSocketService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_CONNECT_WEB_SOCKET:
                Log.d(TAG, "WebSocketService.ACTION_CONNECT_WEB_SOCKET");
                connectToWebSocket();
                break;
            case ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE:
                Log.d(TAG, "WebSocketService.ACTION_SEND_MESSAGE");
                sendMessage();
                break;

        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
    }


    void connectToWebSocket() {

        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(wsuri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
                Log.d(TAG, message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        mWebSocketClient.send("websocket service message");
    }
}
```